# Can't use converted string in @each rule

Tags: sass

I want to use a simple @each rule on elements of a list. The basic code is:

```
$list: 2 "Description 2", 3 "Description 3";
@each $id, $description in $list  {
  [..do sth with the deconstructed elements..]
}
```

And that works just fine. However, I get the values from a string that I first have to split into a list. It looks like this:

```
$string: '2 "Description 2"|3 "Description 3"';
$list: str-split("#{$string}", '|');
@debug $list; //2 "Description 2", 3 "Description 3"

@each $id, $description in $list  {
  [..but it doesn't deconstruct the list..]
}
```

I've tried different functions for splitting or converting the string. Though I always get the  result I want when debugging the variable, I get an error when trying to deconstruct the list: `unterminated attribute selector for id`

I'm a bit lost what I'm missing..

Comment: Can you please also share the `str-split` function you are using?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! I just posted an answer myself, including the function. Would still be curious to hear feedback though, in case there's a better solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it to work. I was assuming Sass is more permissive than it actually is and only split the string into a list (of strings). But I also have to convert each of those strings to a list and generate a nested list.

The code I used:

```
@function str-to-list($string, $separator, $startAt: 1) {
  $item: str-slice($string, $startAt);
  $list: ();
  $index: str-index($item, $separator);
  @if $index == null {
    $list: ($item);
  } @else {
    $list: (str-slice($item, 1, $index - 1));
    $list: join($list, str-to-list($item, $separator, $startAt: $index + 1));
  }
  @return $list;
}
```

```
@import "str-to-list";

$initial_string:'2; Description 2|3; Description 3';
$list: str-to-list("$initial_string, "|");
$nested-list: ();
@each $item in $list {
  $item: str-to-list("#{$item}", ";");
  $nested-list: append($nested-list, $item);
}
@each $id, $description in $nested-list {
  [..do sth with the deconstructed items..]
    }
```